# Why does parent onClick trigger before child onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, onclick, onchange

I have basic HTML in my React project that looks like this:

```
<div
  onClick={(e) => this.handleRowClick(e, id)}>
  <p>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={this.handleSelectOneChange} />
  </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  handleRowClick(event, item_id) {
     // do stuff
  }

  handleSelectOneChange(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

When I click on the checkbox, it fires the `handleRowClick` also in the parent `Div`.  Even though I have a `stopPropagation()` in the child function.  However, when I log, it calls the parent function before the child (checkbox) function so I can see why `stopPropagation()` is not working.

Is there a better way to do this?  Or will I just have to check what type of element is being clicked before doing anything.  For example, in the parent click function, don't do anything if the "target" is a checkbox.  Is seems like that is a hack and not the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the checkbox click produces a click event before a change event. You may have to add an onclick to the input and prevent its propagation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely that clicking on the checkbox triggers a 'click' event that's bubbling up to the div. So you may want to capture the input click event before it bubbles.

How about trying this:

```html
<input
  type="checkbox"
  onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick}
  onChange={this.handleSelectOneChange} />
```

```js
this.handleCheckboxClick(evt) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This snippet shows the sequence of events. Clicking the checkbox produces these events in this order:

> input onclick
>   div onclick
>   input onchange

```html
<div onclick="console.log('div onclick');">
  Checkbox:
  <input type="checkbox"
    onclick="console.log('input onclick');"
    onchange="console.log('input onchange');" />
</div>
```

Comment: Simple but great solution, this helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Surely the click event will hit . since the checkbox is wrapped in a div which has already a click event and the click event is having more priority than onChange, to handle the logic in here you have to use

`e.target.id or e.target.name` in order to identify the element.